# Sql duplicate record query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq

I have two tables.

1. MasterStudent (student_number,name,address,dob)
2. Boarding point (boardingID,student_number, number of sections)

I want to get duplicate students by birthday, but I am not sure how to get the duplicate records. I am new in sql. I tried this query:

```sql
SELECT T.GivenName + ' ' + T.SurName AS Name,
  T.StreetNumber + ' ' + T.StreetName + ' ' + T.Suburb + ' ' + T.PostCode + ' ' + T.State + ' ' + T.Country AS Address,
  T.Sex, 
  T.DateOfBirth,
  T.yearlevel AS Year,
  z.dupCount,
  T.StudentNumber
FROM tblMasterStudent AS T
INNER JOIN (SELECT DateOfBirth, COUNT(*) AS dupCount
            FROM tblMasterStudent
            GROUP BY DateOfBirth
            HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)) AS z ON z.DateOfBirth = T.DateOfBirth
            ORDER BY z.dupCount DESC
```

It is fetching the duplicate records by birthday from the MasterStudent table but i want to get the records from masterStudent+BoardingPoint

Comment: i have two tables tblMasterStudent and tblBoardingPoint

Comment: isn't it just another `INNER JOIN tblBoardingPoint USING(student_number)` before the `ORDER BY z.dupCount DESC`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by birthdays and look at all the birthdays that occur more than once:

```
SELECT count(1) as frequency, dob
FROM students
GROUP BY dob
HAVING frequency > 1;
```